# Is using a firewall debit card (curve) a good solution to protect my main credit card?

Tags: credit-card, fraud, online-banking, security

I'm using [Curve](https://www.curve.com/), a physical debit card that connects all your credit and debit cards in one and let you decide which one to use at each transaction by using its own app.

I've used it with my lower limit credit cards and I really enjoy its features (like instant notifications etc).
I recently managed to get a premium credit card from my bank and I wanted to ask you if you think it's a good idea to link it to this service (or similar ones) in a way to protect my main premium credit card data to be exposed online and in real life. I would store my premium credit card in a safe place and spend with this curve card.

Is this a good idea from a security standpoint?

In particular I'm concerned about my credit card being cloned and not being aware of it (because I may not have all the time needed to check each transaction at the end of the month). So I thought that if I never make any purchase directly with it, it would be harder to fraud me. Also in my bank statement all the transaction made via Curve will be reported as: "Curve....", so it could be easier for me to check if there's something suspicious going on. Moreover whenever I use my curve card I get an instant notification which could alert me.
On the other hand I'm worried that Curve is not secure enough and may be hacked or something with all my credit cards details being exposed.

The question is: is using curve or similar firewall cards options a good practice that enhances security instead of using directly the original credit card?

---

PS. Original question was posted [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232872/is-using-a-firewall-debit-card-a-good-solution-to-protect-my-main-credit-card?noredirect=1#comment476060_232872) and I was asked to post here in moneySE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check local consumer protection regulations for debit cards vs credit cards. [In the US credit cards have stronger protections then debit cards](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/are-credit-cards-safer-than-debit-cards/). For example, if someone steals your credit card and goes on a shopping spree, the most you will be held responsible for is $50. For debit cards your liability increases if you delay reporting the theft. After 60 days your liability is unlimited. Credit cards may also provide consumer protection plans that offer some insurance against theft or destruction of the goods you've purchased.

On the other hand, credit cards in the US typically charge interest on cash advances starting as soon as you receive the advance. Debit cards don't charge interest on cash withdrawals, since no credit is being extended.

Comment: Ultimately a credit card is charged either way, so it seems like the protections would hold regardless?

Comment: @Kat That will depend very strongly on how local law treats Curve. They could treat it as two separate transactions: a cash advance on your credit card that gets deposited to your Curve account followed by a purchase on your Curve debit card. You'd have to look at the details of Curve's customer agreement and local law.

Comment: Also look very closely at how your credit card treats that. It sounds like a balance transfer from curve to the other card, which will often accrue interest differently.