# Is there a good solution to not paying extra charges when paying by payment card?

Tags: credit-card, scams, debit-card, charges

One hears about situations where someone legitimately pays using a payment card, but further charges are made unexpectedly.  Examples include [additional charges](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2023/dec/26/green-motion-hire-car-broke-down-then-we-were-charged-2600) determined by the company without approval from the customer, [charges determined in error](https://www.theguardian.com/money/2024/feb/28/tfls-ulez-auto-pay-has-turned-out-to-be-an-auto-fine) and [signing up to repeated payments](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/04/03/us/politics/trump-donations.html) when a single payment was expected.

Is there a way to avoid this possibility?  It seems that pre-payment cards could be an option, where one adds only what is required for each payment.  However this is a certain amount of effort, and apparently [they are not accepted everywhere](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/credit-cards/prepaid-cards/#accordion-content-0295000688-4).  A service such as curve mentioned in [a previous answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126347/is-using-a-firewall-debit-card-curve-a-good-solution-to-protect-my-main-credit) may be a solution, but the functionality is not obviously touted on their [web site](https://www.curve.com/).

Comment: Are you asking about fees or repeating charges? These are different things

Comment: I do not mean fees added on top of the advertised price, I mean additional charges made in subsequent transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual credit cards are a solution that is increasingly popular. Implementations vary, but they are generated card numbers that you can use online or in person at places that accept mobile payments (like Google/Apple pay). The transactions show up on your credit card account.

Some virtual card features that you might have access to:

- Ability to toggle on/off (turn it off and new charges won't be approved)
- Set spending limits (charges will not be approved if above your set limit)
- Set specific store(s) it can be used at
- Usable while waiting for physical card (replacement or with new account)
- Can be single-use

At my bank, I can create up to 20 virtual credit cards per day, so I can use them as single-use credit cards if desired.

In the US, fraudulent/erroneous credit card charges are typically easy to clear up. Virtual credit cards can add an extra layer of protection, especially helpful with vendors/services you've not used before or don't trust.

Comment: Could you detail how this would work to solve the problem I highlight?  I looked [here](https://n26.com/en-eu/virtual-card) and [here](https://wise.com/gb/virtual-card/) and it is not clear how they would protect against subsequent charges being made when one only expected to pay once.

Comment: @User65535 it wouldn't if the merchant claims the charges are authorized. Basically, as long as the merchant has your payment information and your authorization - they'll be able to charge you. Fortunately, with credit cards, chargebacks are easier than with debit cards/checks, and card processors drop merchants who abuse the system and end up with too many chargebacks.

Comment: @User65535 Features vary, but most of the bulleted items would limit/prevent unexpected charges. When turned off no transactions will be approved. If the spending limit is exceeded the charge will not go through. I use them infrequently, so they're basically single-use credit cards when I do.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if the merchant has your payment information and your authorization, the credit card issuer will not prevent them from charging you unless you're exceeding your credit limit. The recurring charges are marked as such and will follow you even if you reissue the card as lost/stolen/forged with a different number.

Luckily, you can dispute transactions, and the responsibility to prove you've given a proper authorization is on the merchant. If the merchants can't or won't provide such a proof to their processor, the charge will be reversed.

Processors routinely drop merchants with too many chargebacks, because otherise the networks drop processors who allow their merchants to have too many chargebacks. As such, oftentimes just a threat of a chargeback can be enough to convince a misbehaving merchant to refund you.

You can also complain about misleading business practices to your regulators (e.g.: the FTC in the US, or State regulators). Consumer advocates like the BBB or the local news can also help.

Some banks come out with some products that allow more tailored customization of how the card can be used, as described in the other answer about virtual cards, but those are rare and not very effective.